# How to update div using Reimer ASP.NET control?

Tags: asp.net, html, .net-4.0, google-maps-markers

I'm using Reimers ASP.NET control wich is great. But now I'm having a little  problem. 
I add two pins on the map like you can see in the following code below. When I click those markers on the map, map_OverlayClick method is executed but it does not change the text in divTest. It could also be label, textbox or whatever. What can I do to update this div with the new text ?

I'm trying to do something similar to [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features.html) with the Reimers control.

[Reimers asp.net map control](http://reimers.dk)

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Reimers.Google.Map" Namespace="Reimers.Google.Map" TagPrefix="Reimers" %>
   <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
      <Reimers:Map ID="Map1" runat="server" Width="400" Height="400" DefaultMapType="Terrain">
   </Reimers:Map>
<div id="divTest" runat="server" />
```

Code behinde:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            divTest.InnerHtml = "First div text...";
            LatLng laln = new LatLng();
            laln.Latitude = 65;
            laln.Longitude = -19;

            Marker marker = new Marker(65.4, -18.5);
            Map1.Overlays.Add(marker);

            Marker marker1 = new Marker(65.4, -18.3);
            Map1.Overlays.Add(marker1);

            Map1.Zoom = 7;
            Map1.Center = laln;
        }

        Map1.OverlayClick += map_OverlayClick;
    }

    void map_OverlayClick(object sender, OverlayEventArgs e)
    {
        divTest.InnerHtml = "Second div text..";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.reimers.dk/tutorials/handling-map-events), then you will see that the pattern is to assign a JavaScript command to the MapCommand property of the event args (OverlayEventArgs).

In your case, what you want is to execute:

```
document.getElementById("divTest").innerHTML = "Second div";
```

So you have to assign that command to the MapCommand, like so:

```
e.MapCommand = "document.getElementById(\"divTest\").innerHTML = \"Second div\";";
```

If you use jQuery or some other clientside framework, you can of course reference that, since the map control simply executes the JavaScript you hand it from the server.

A better option is probably to set the command to the appropriate clientside handler  (dummy code: Marker.ClientsideHandlers.OnClick = "your JavaScript code") if you don't need any server processing.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do what you told me to. But I'm not getting it to work. When I run this in Google Chrome I get the following error in the javascript: _italic_Default.aspx:92 Uncaught ReferenceError: divTest is not defined (repeated 6 times)_italic_.

Comment: I also tried this and not getting it to work either:  Marker marker = new Marker(65.4, -18.5); marker.ClientSideHandlers.OnClick = "document.getElementById(\"divTest\").innerHTML = \"mark2\";"; marker.Clickable = true; Map1.Overlays.Add(marker);

Comment: divTest is supposed to be the clientside ID of the div you are trying to reference. You need to modify the code to make sure that it matches whatever is your code is.

Comment: I see that now. My clientside div ID was MainContent_divTest but I was using divTest because that was the ID I used in my code. Thank you very much for your answer! :)